# Consider the simple program. Where are these errors?

Tags: c, syntax

I have written a simple C program in Eclipse as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {

    float x1, y1, z1;
    float x2, y2, z2;
    float d;

    printf("Enter the x y and z coordinates of point 1: ");

    while (scanf("%f %f %f", &x1, &y1, &z1) == 3) {

        printf("Enter the x y and z coordinates of point 2: ");

        while (scanf("%f %f %f", &x2, &y2, &z2) == 3) {

            d = sqrtf( pow((x2 – x1), 2.0) + pow((y2 – y1), 2.0) + pow((z2 – z1), 2.0) );

            printf("The distance between point 1 and point 2 is %f\n", d);

        }

    }

return(0);

}
```

I am getting very strange errors when building it and can't see a problem:

> Problem expected expression before '%' token UNDEE601W10A1p6.c
>   /UNDEE601W10A1 line 12 C/C++
>
> Problem expected expression before '%' token UNDEE601W10A1p6.c
>   /UNDEE601W10A1 line 16 C/C++  Problem expected declaration or
>   statement at end of input UNDEE601W10A1p6.c /UNDEE601W10A1 line 26
>   C/C++
>
> Problem expected ')' before 'z1' UNDEE601W10A1p6.c /UNDEE601W10A1 line
>   18 C/C++
>
> Problem expected ')' before 'y1' UNDEE601W10A1p6.c /UNDEE601W10A1 line
>   18 C/C++
>
> Problem expected ')' before 'x1' UNDEE601W10A1p6.c /UNDEE601W10A1 line
>   18 C/C++
>
> Problem expected ')' before 'the' UNDEE601W10A1p6.c /UNDEE601W10A1
>   line 10 C/C++
>
> Problem expected ')' before 'the' UNDEE601W10A1p6.c /UNDEE601W10A1
>   line 14 C/C++
>
> Problem expected ')' before 'distance' UNDEE601W10A1p6.c
>   /UNDEE601W10A1 line 20 C/C++
>
> Problem 'The' undeclared (first use in this function)
>   UNDEE601W10A1p6.c /UNDEE601W10A1 line 20 C/C++
>
> Problem 'Enter' undeclared (first use in this function)
>   UNDEE601W10A1p6.c /UNDEE601W10A1 line 10 C/C++
>
> Problem variable 'd' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
>   UNDEE601W10A1p6.c /UNDEE601W10A1 line 8 C/C++
>
> Problem unused variable 'z1' [-Wunused-variable] UNDEE601W10A1p6.c
>   /UNDEE601W10A1 line 6 C/C++
>
> Problem unused variable 'y1' [-Wunused-variable] UNDEE601W10A1p6.c
>   /UNDEE601W10A1 line 6 C/C++
>
> Problem unused variable 'x1' [-Wunused-variable] UNDEE601W10A1p6.c
>   /UNDEE601W10A1 line 6 C/C++
>
> Problem each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each
>   function it appears in UNDEE601W10A1p6.c /UNDEE601W10A1 line 10 C/C++
>   Problem

Any help would be appreciated.

Norman

Answer (score 0):

In sqrtf Function for subtraction you are using wrong symbol,
you should use "-" instead of "–"